# timestamp in SQLite - Android

Tags: android, timestamp, android-sqlite

I am new to android and creating an application with sqlite database.

I am using SQLite browser to create database in android. I just want to create a time stamp filed just like mysql. But in SQLite browser there is no such field like timestamp.

My little question is is it possible to add the timestamp field in sqlite and query order by the timestamp field

Answer (score 1):

There is no any date format in `sqlite` only `TEXT` please [read this link](http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-insert-datetime-value-in-sqlite-database/)
You should hold your Date as text in `ISO8601 ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS")` format

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if I just wanna sort the query according to date time how we can do this ?

Comment: Sorting TEXT type column with your data in `ISO8601` format should work well because it got `Lexicographical order`